# Incorrect Network

Tags: network, ledger-hardware-wallet, binance

I was hoping someone could help with a transaction please.

I sent BTC to my binance account via my ledger. I think I used BTC segwit to send but sent it to the BTC address on binance- I was not aware there was a BTC segwit address on binance when sending.

Will I still receive the BTC in my binance account as the BTC address was still connected to my binance account?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's distinction of "bitcoin" and "bitcoin segwit". It's just Bitcoin.

Comment: Does that mean the bitcoin will arrive? its been over an hour- so I sent it on BTC segwit but to a BTC address.

Comment: Yes. They're identical and still processed the same. You can use a tool like https://mempoo.space to estimate confirmation time.

Comment: You're a star- thought i'd lost my BTC. Guess I have to wait a while due to using a low fee. Cheers mate.

Comment: You're welcome. I can't edit my comment, but I meant mempool.space as the tool to use to check confirmation time. best of luck.

Comment: Hey sorry to bug you again- if you get this notification could you please take a look at my transaction to see how long it should take. Its been there over 12 hours now.

5c119ce4b0bce440c16b2ad48e720c22422454118bf15ece0602904349d0b568